# pd.read_csv: utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 61: invalid start byte

Tags: python, csv, input, unicode, utf-8

I want to download a csv file from: https://www.osha.gov/fatalities/reports/archive.

[image]

Please try the FY15 one.

My code is like:

```
a=pd.read_csv('C://.../fy15_federal-state_summaries.csv',encoding = "utf-8")
```

But I still have got the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 61: invalid start byte
```

I have also tried different ways. But all do not work. Could anyone help me here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `encoding` issue.

You need to find out the correct encoding of the file.

In this case it is `1250`, so:

```
a=pd.read_csv(r'C:\...\fy15_federal-state_summaries.csv',encoding = "1250")
```

Comment: So, how can i find which encoding one file uses? Thanks

Comment: As far as i know there isn't a reliable way to do it.
One way that sometimes can help is to use Text Editors that indicating the encoding of the file (like Notepadd++) - but, like in this case, it not always helpful.
The better solution is common sense.