# Fixing a CSV File reading error in Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to read data from a CSV file into Python but I keep getting the error:

"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 16: invalid start byte"

My code:

```
f = open('/Users/zach/Downloads/xo april 2020.csv', 'r')
fileContents = f.read().splitlines()
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pd.read\_csv: utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 61: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57899487/pd-read-csv-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x98-in-position-61-invalid-start-b)

Comment: it seems this file is not in `UTF-8` but other encoding and you have to set it manually in - ie, `open(..., encoding="latin1")`. BTW: you may try to use module `chardet` (char detection) to recognize encoding - but first you have to read it in `bytes` mode - `rb`

Comment: It looks like your default encoding is UTF-8 but your file isn't encoded that way. This is a common occurrence in Windows where files are often written in a computers default code page encoding or in UTF-16. Its hard for us to guess what the encoding is. You could open the file in binary and print out a couple of lines, which may help decide if its UTF-16.

Comment: @furas I tried adding the encoding="latin1" but it returned a ton of characters and symbols in an unintelligible manor. I guess this might be because it is trying to use the module chardet and not use bytes but I do not know how to change that.

Comment: `latin1` was only example - you may have file in different encoding `cp1250`, `latin2`, and many, many others. Maybe find in Google what encoding may use char with code `0x98` See also [Standard encodings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings)

Comment: BTW: if you use `MacOS` then it may use `mac_latin2` or `mac_roman` - you may use  `try/except` with `for encoding in ('mac_latin2', 'mac_roman', 'latin1', ...): ...open(..., encoding=encoding)` to test different encodings.

Comment: BTW, the fact that the file is in csv format really has no bearing on the problem (at least as far as the code currently in your question goes).